# why the time complexity is n*n*n! for the below algorithm printing all the permutation of a string?

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, runtime

I understand the n! because line no 7 has to be executed n!  times for the program to print all the permutation of the string. where does the n*n comes from is not it less than n! so should be ignored.

```
1. void perm(String str){
2.    perm(str, "");
3.  }
4.
5. void perm(String str, String prefix){
6.     if(str.length() == 0){
7.         System.out.println(prefix);
8.     } else{
9.        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
10.           String rem = str.substring(0, i) + 
                           str.substring(i + 1);
11.           perm(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
12.       }
13.    }
14. }
```

Comment: It has to be executed far more than 7 times. You're not counting what happens in the recursions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of string concatenation dificulty. Trry to use StringBuilder :

```
StringBuilder rem = new StringBuilder();
rem.append(str.substring(0, i)).append(str.substring(i + 1))
perm(rem.toString(), prefix + str.charAt(i));
```